# How to increase the padding (or margins) for an item/row in a QListWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

We're looking for a way to increase the padding (or margins) for a `QListWidget` we are using in our application. We'd like to increase this for all four directions to give the text in our list some extra space

I've looked at the documentation for both [`QListWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget-members.html) and [`QListWidgetItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem-members.html) and can't find anything. For `QListWidget` there's `setContentsMargins` which is inherited from `QWidget` but that is for the widget as a whole (rather than individual entries).

What can we do to solve this? Grateful for help!

Comment: How are you creating the `QListWidgetItem` list for the `QListWidget`?

Comment: What about [`setContentsMargins`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setContentsMargins) and/or [`setSpacing`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#spacing-prop)?

Comment: @G.M. `setSpacing` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Cant believe that it is 2024 and we still have to hack this using style sheets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`setSpacing(int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#spacing-prop) will increase the padding in all directions

(Thank you G.M. for your help!)

Comment: is it possible to increase only the bottom spacing (margin ?)

Answer (score 7):

how about this

```
ui->listWidget->setStyleSheet("QListWidget {padding: 10px;} QListWidget::item { margin: 10px; }");
```

Answer (score 2):

## we use css selector for thise

```
list = QListWidget()
list.addItem("item 1")
list.addItem("item 2")
list.addItem("item 3")

list.setStyleSheet("""
    QListWidget {
        background-color: red;
        padding:20px;

    }
    QListWidget::item {
        margin:20px;
        background-color: blue;

    }
""")
```